# ajax controls in windows application using c#

Tags: c#

how we can use ajax controls in windows form using c#

Comment: do you even understand what is ajax controls ? It's html + javascript + css, so ... you can do something ugly with a browser control, but I won't suggest you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is Asynchronous Javascript and XML which is a web technology. I am pretty sure that the functionality provided by AJAX Controls are definitely available for WinForms. Calendar controls, Color pickers, Sliders etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding what Ajax is. It is a web technology to get around the lack of interactive functionality available in the disconnected model of a web page in a browser. You don't need this in a Windows forms app - the interactivity is there already.

Answer (score 2):

By adding a [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control to the form that will point to the ASP.NET web site using these AJAX controls. This is to say that AJAX is used in web applications and not windows.